# Convert on the fly managed item in a for:each

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, type-conversion

Let's see this simple scenario:

```
String ids = "10_20_30_40";
for (String idString : ids.split("_")) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(idString);
}
```

There is a way to avoid this conversion and get the `int` value directly? Something like:

```
for (int id : Integer.parseEach(ids.split("_"))) {

}
```

or

```
for (int id : ids.split("_").stream(...)) {

}
```

Comment: Is that one line code biting you like a bee?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi nope, but with new Java-8 features like streams maybe there is a more beautiful way to do it... just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options come to mind. It would be good to extract the content of the for loop in a method, say `void useId(int id)`

You could use `Pattern::splitAsStream`:

```
Pattern underscore = Pattern.compile("_");
underscore.splitAsStream(ids)
        .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .forEach(this::useId);
```

Or you could simply stream the result of split:

```
Arrays.stream(ids.split("_")).mapToInt(...)...
```

Or, you could create an array:

```
for (int id : underscore.splitAsStream(ids).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray()) {

}
```

or... you could keep your for loop!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
String ids = "10_20_30_40";
Arrays.stream(ids.split("_")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
    .forEachOrdered(id -> {
        System.out.println(id);
    });
```